# How to generate or create iBeacons UUID?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Apple released iOS 7 with iBeacons technology. Does Apple release any more details about this iBeacons technology?

In my project, I will create an iBeacons. How can I pick the UUID of iBeacons? 
Is there any rules to generate iBeacons UUID? 
Can I use random number as UUID?

Comment: I would like to generate UUID as well. The purpose of doing this is to avoid overlapping of UUID with other iBeacon. But the answers below does not answer this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the uuidgen command in Terminal to generate a UUID, create an NSUUID and
then instantiate a CLBeaconRegion instance:

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"10D39AE7-020E-4467-9CB2-DD36366F899D"];

CLBeaconRegion *region = [CLBeaconRegion initWithProximityUUID:uuid
                                                    identifier:@"unique region identifier"];
```

See Apple's AirLocate sample project from WWDC 2013 for more info or you can review my blog here for more info: http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/christopher-mann/ios-7-tutorial-series-core-location-beacons.

Answer (score 8):

If your question was more about where to generate proximity UUID for iBeacon app, I suggest using free online application OpenUUID we have created:

http://openuuid.net/

Besides generating unique proximity UUIDs for your apps (OpenUUID detects collisions, even though their probability is astronomically small), OpenUUID lets you access the list of UUIDs that you previously generated, so that you can keep track of them. Hope the service helps...

Comment: Thanks for the link @bummi but... I mean... Is my answer really a "promotion", or did I add some information that can be directly used to solve the question being asked? What specific issue do you have with the answer? And please try to be little "realistic" here, not just beating me with a stick... ;-)

Comment: The views differ widely in this respect, take a look on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) regarding this theme. I did not beat you, just provided a link, trying to avoid that you might get in trouble.

Comment: OK, basically I have read first 5 threads on "[promotion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=promotion)" at Meta. They often lead to [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers) and yes, I did make one big mistake in the original post: I didn't affiliate myself with the product publicly. I will fix this...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/whats-new-in-bluetooth-le-ios-7/

Seems to indicate you could just use [UUID UUIDString]